# Python make list of tuples from two lists and a constant

Tags: python, list, tuples

I would like to make a list of tuples using two lists and a constant, as follows, I'd like to generate ob in the fast way possible. I need to make about a hundred thousand of these, so time matters...

On average the size A and B have a length of about 1000

```
constant = 3
A = [1,2,3]
B = [0.1,0.2,0.3]
ob = [(3,1,0.1),(3,2,0.2),(3,3,0.3)]
```

I know zip(A,B) can create a list of tuples but I need the constant at the beginning. Here is the code I am using at them moment, I was wondering if there is a faster way to do this

```
ob = []
for i in xrange(len(A)):
    a = A[i]
    b = B[i]
    ob.append((constant,a,b))

print ob
```

Comment: You could use [**`itertools.repeat`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat)

Comment: How about simply using `print (list(zip([constant]*len(A),A,B)))`. Output is `[(3, 1, 0.1), (3, 2, 0.2), (3, 3, 0.3)]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [**`itertools.repeat`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat):

```
from itertools import repeat

ob = list(zip(repeat(constant), A, B))
```

Comment: It should be `zip(repeat(constant),A, B)`

Comment: avoiding python loops is the best bet.

Answer (score 3):

I suggestion the following solution still based on [`zip()` built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip), without any needed import directive:

```
constant = 3
A = [1,2,3]
B = [0.1,0.2,0.3]

ob = list(zip([constant]*len(A), A ,B))

print(ob)  # [(3,1,0.1),(3,2,0.2),(3,3,0.3)]
```

Comment: Dude, you and me have synchronized minds :) Check my comment

Answer (score 1):

use [itertools.cycle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle)

```
import itertools 
ob = list( zip( itertools.cycle([3]) , A , B ) )
```